# fscanf line with condition

Tags: c++, fgets, scanf

my goal is to read in a data file consisting of just one number per line and write the data into a histogram. There are some comments in the file behind `#` characters. I want to skip these lines.

I have started writing:

```
TH1F *hist = new TH1F("hist","",4096, -0.5,4095.5);
//TF1 *fitfunc;

char filename[100];
double val;
int i;
char line[256];


sprintf(filename,"test.dat");
FILE* pfile = fopen(filename, "r");

for (i=0;i<=14;i++) {
    fgets(line,256,pfile);
    cout<<line<<endl;
    fscanf(pfile, "%lf /n", &val);
    hist->SetBinContent(i,val);
}
```

But only every other line gets written as "line" while the others are fscanfed.

Would be very nice, if someone could give me a hint.

...so this will obviously not work properly:

```
TH1F *hist = new TH1F("hist","",4096, -0.5,4095.5);
//TF1 *fitfunc;

char filename[100];
double val;
int i;
char zeile[256];

sprintf(filename,"test.dat");
FILE* pfile = fopen(filename, "r");

for (i=0;i<=14;i++) 
{
    fgets(zeile,256,pfile);
    cout<<"fgets: "<<zeile<<endl;
    if (zeile[0]!='#')
    {
        fscanf(pfile, "%lf /n", &val);
        cout<<"val: "<<val<<endl;
        hist->SetBinContent(i,val);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `sscanf()` to parse what `fgets()` read. You probably meant `\n` rather than `/n`. While you can get away with trailing white space in format string for file input, it is an awful idea to include trailing white space in an interactive format string — one where the user is expected to type at the terminal. The white space won't be satisfied until the user types something other than white space (newlines count as white space). So if you have trailing white space in the format string, the user has to guess what is the next character to type in order to finish the current input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sscanf()` instead of `fscanf()` after you've read the line with `fgets()`:

```
TH1F *hist = new TH1F("hist", "", 4096, -0.5, 4095.5);
char filename[100];
char zeile[256];

sprintf(filename, "test.dat");
FILE *pfile = fopen(filename, "r");
if (pfile == 0)
    …handle error; do not continue…

for (int i = 0; i < 14 && fgets(zeile, sizeof(zeile), pfile) != 0; i++) 
{
    cout << "fgets: " << zeile << endl;
    if (zeile[0] != '#')
    {
        double val;
        if (sscanf(zeile, "%lf", &val) == 1)
        {
            cout << "val: " << val << endl;
            hist->SetBinContent(i, val);
        }
        // else … optionally report that line was erroneous
    }
}
```

I left the `sprintf()` for the file name in place, but it provides marginal value.  I'd be tempted to use `const char *filename = "test.dat";` so that the error message can report the file name that failed to open without repeating the string literal.

Converted into a standalone test program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char filename[100];
    char zeile[256];

    sprintf(filename, "test.dat");
    FILE *pfile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (pfile != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 14 && fgets(zeile, sizeof(zeile), pfile) != 0; i++) 
        {
            cout << "fgets: " << zeile;
            if (zeile[0] != '#')
            {
                double val;
                if (sscanf(zeile, "%lf", &val) == 1)
                    cout << "val: " << val << endl;
            }
        }
        fclose(pfile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and given a test data file `test.dat` containing:

```
1.234
2.345
#3.456
#4.567
5.678
```

the output from the program shown is:

```
fgets: 1.234
val: 1.234
fgets: 2.345
val: 2.345
fgets: #3.456
fgets: #4.567
fgets: 5.678
val: 5.678
```

This generates the three expected `val` lines and reads but ignores the two comment lines.